# CLISTs in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, clist

I have cpp code where the struct objects are put into the `CLISTS`. I am porting this code into Objective C.

CLIST is similar to a doubly linked list with `.RemoveAt` , `.GetAt` , `.InsertBefore` , `.GetNext` , `.GetHeadPosition` functions.

How to implement the same in `Objective C`.
Do I need to implement doubly linked list in Objective C.Is there any other predefined methods to use it.

Answer (score 1):

A CLIST is presumably circular? Hence the `GetHeadPosition`?

In any case, `NSArray` (or, `NSMutableArray` in this case, since you want to be inserting) is the normal way to keep ordered lists in Objective-C.

For `RemoveAt`, use `removeObjectAtIndex:`. For `GetAt`, use `objectAtIndex:`. For `InsertBefore` you're probably going to want to write a little something like:

```
- (void)insert:(id)objectToInsert before:(id)referenceObject
{
    int index = [array indexOfObject:referenceObject];

    if(index == NSNotFound) return; // or whatever you'd expect. 
                                    // Maybe object is just inserted at the end?

    index = index - 1;
    if(index < 0) index = [array count];
    [array insertObject:objectToInsert atIndex:index];
}
```

(which would probably go better in an NSArray category, but you get the point)

For `GetNext` and `GetHeadPosition` you probably want to keep your array position in a separate variable. So for GetNext:

```
arrayPosition = (arrayPosition + 1)%[array count];
return [array objectAtIndex:arrayPosition];
```

And for GetHeadPosition, just:

```
return arrayPosition;
```

EDIT: for iterating through an NSArray, the easiest way is actually to ignore anything explicit and just use:

```
for(ObjectType *object in array)
{
     /* do something with object */
}
```

That generally means you don't really need an analogue of GetNext, but you can't mutate the array while in that loop so it's not always usable.